# Ingress-Nginx w/ Kubernetes not getting IP address

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and am attempting to get `Ingress-Nginx` to work on my local k8s cluster.

I have it installed and running:

```
$ kubectl get pods --namespace=ingress-nginx
  NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  nginx-ingress-controller-76f97b74b-bbb6h   1/1     Running   0          13h
```

Then I created two nginx services (wanted to test name-based routing):

```
$ kubectl get svc
  NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
    kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        20h
    nginx        NodePort    10.102.188.253   <none>        80:32025/TCP   36m
    nginx2       NodePort    10.109.43.89     <none>        80:32458/TCP   35m
```

And I created my ingress:

```
$ kubectl get ingress -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2018-10-25T12:27:44Z
    generation: 1
    name: test
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "98114"
    selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/test
    uid: 5fbc2e9e-d851-11e8-995f-2ae1e5e17bac
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: test-ingress.chbresser.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: nginx
            servicePort: 80
    - host: test-ingress2.chbresser.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: nginx2
            servicePort: 80
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

From my understanding that is all I was supposed to do, but its not getting an IP address:

```
$ kubectl get ingress
  NAME   HOSTS                                                    ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
    test   test-ingress.chbresser.com,test-ingress2.chbresser.com             80      33m
```

What step did I miss? Why am I not getting an IP?

Edit:

`kubectl logs nginx-ingress-controller-76f97b74b-bbb6h --namespace=ingress-nginx:`

```
W1025 05:44:10.003587       9 queue.go:130] requeuing &ObjectMeta{Name:sync status,GenerateName:,Namespace:,SelfLink:,UID:,ResourceVersion:,Generation:0,CreationTimestamp:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,DeletionTimestamp:<nil>,DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:nil,Labels:map[string]string{},Annotations:map[string]string{},OwnerReferences:[],Finalizers:[],ClusterName:,Initializers:nil,}, err services "ingress-nginx" not found
```

Comment: Have you tried to do `kubectl logs nginx-ingress-controller-76f97b74b-bbb6h --watch` while creating your ingress definition. You should see that the ingress-controller logs an update message in the logs when doing so. If there is no upate, probably the discovery does not work.

Comment: see my edit. It looks like it is looking for a service called ingress-nginx but the docs only have you deploy it using: `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml`, it doesn't mention a service at all.

Comment: Have you tried to use command `kubectl get svc --namespace=ingress-nginx ` to see service for your ingress controller?

Comment: yes it is there.

Answer (score 2):

I use Bare-metal and get IP address by using `--report-node-internal-ip-address=true` 
flag in `ingress-controller`.

Here is my `ingress-controller` yaml:

```html
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        k8s-app: ingress-nginx
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - args: 
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - "--default-backend-service=default/my-app"
            - "--report-node-internal-ip-address=true"
          env: 
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom: 
                fieldRef: 
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom: 
                fieldRef: 
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          image: "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0"
          name: nginx-ingress-controller
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 80
              hostPort: 80
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
```

my `ingress` yaml:

```html
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  name: my-app
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-app.example.com
    http: 
     paths:
     - path: /
       backend:
        serviceName: my-app
        servicePort: 80
```

and result:

```html
$ kubectl get ing
NAME     HOSTS   ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
my-app   *       192.168.1.78   80      40h

$ kubectl get svc
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          8d
my-app            ClusterIP   10.110.152.216   <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP   8d

$ kubectl get po
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-app-rc-d7lw9                             1/1     Running   0          8d
my-app-rc-spvjb                             1/1     Running   0          8d
my-app-rc-tvkrw                             1/1     Running   0          8d
nginx-ingress-controller-6c6c899467-d9sg6   1/1     Running   0          16m
```

for more detail , see [this issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1750).

Answer (score 1):

Can you check this issue if it is related to yours. You might have to upgrade your ingress controller.

[git issue for ingress controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/204)

Looking at your edit. It seems you have not applied service for your nginx controller and hence it is not able to find the related srvc .

Check if there is a srvc under namespace ingress-nginx by running below command

> kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx

If it isnt present ,apply the provider specific service.

for example, below one for bare-metal provider

> kubectl apply -f
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml

Comment: I think that is a different `nginx-ingress` that looks to be created by nginxinc where as I am using the [one made by kubernetes](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#verify-installation)

Comment: can you check "kubectl get svc -n kube-system" and see if there is a svc for your nginx controller and also kubectl get svc --all-namespaces

Comment: did you apply this kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml

Comment: it seems service is not applied for the nginx controller .Can you check applying the service. first check if there is a service under namespace "ingress-nginx". you can check that using  kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx

Comment: I did not apply the service, and I have done so. But still no IP for the ingress.

Comment: what does the kubectl logs nginx-ingress-controller-76f97b74b-bbb6h --namespace=ingress-nginx: say now ?

Comment: same thing. I have verified that it the service is present and running.

Comment: what is the type of service , loadbalancer or nodeport ? Can you describe the service?