# Nginx Ingress Failing to Serve

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, kubeadm, nginx-ingress

I am new to k8s 
I have a deployment file that goes below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: jenkins
          image: jenkins
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 50000
```

My Service File is as following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: jenkins-svc
spec:
   type: ClusterIP
   ports:
   - port: 80
     targetPort: 8080
     name: http
   selector:
      component: web
```

My Ingress File is

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: jenkins.xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: jenkins-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

I am using the nginx ingress project and my cluster is created using kubeadm with 3 nodes
[nginx ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)

I first ran the mandatory command

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
```

when I tried hitting jenkins.xyz.com it didn't work 
when I tried the command

```
  kubectl get ing
```

the ing resource doesnt get an IP address assigned to it

Comment: Did you update your DNS record so that your "jenkins.xyz.com" is resolved to nginx-ingress-controller's IP?  What is the error when hitting jenkins.xyz.com?

Comment: Hello  I am not aware about the dns record  I will check about it when I hit jenkis.xyz.com  I get a 504  Gateway time out

Comment: I recently saw this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989993/ingress-nginx-w-kubernetes-not-getting-ip-address 
and applied the command 
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml
then when I ran the command kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
I see a cluster IP and ports 80:30859, 443:31064 and the External IP is none

Comment: Yes, you would need to use "Load-Balancer" type for your Service such that your cloud provider would give you an IP. In your config it is a "NodePort" Service, so it would not be assigned an IP. You could take a look at my answer here for understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784460/aws-vpc-k8s-load-balancing/54787219#54787219

Comment: Hello I am sorry dint completely understand   Do I have to In My Jenkins-Service File  change the type of Service from ClusterIP to LoadBalancer ? I did try doing that but faced the same issue

Comment: It seemed that you need some reading of those concepts before proceeding. Please read through the official doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/. The main point is,  you would need to have all your traffic go into your nginx-ingress-controller pod and your nginx-ingress-controller pod will route based on your ingress configured. Ingress is just a Config ( not pod ). Think of it as a location block in your nginx config.

Comment: Where is your Kubernetes cluster running? You didn't finish the nginx ingress installation. In addition to `mandatory.yaml` you need to deploy one of the provider specific manifests at https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#provider-specific-steps.

Comment: Hello I am running my cluster in virtual machines so I will have to apply the yaml for bare metal right?

Answer (score 1):

The ingress resource is nothing but the configuration of a reverse proxy (the `Ingress controller`).

It is normal that the `Ingress` doesn't get an IP address assigned.

What you need to do is connect to your ingress controller instance(s).

In order to do so, you need to understand how they're exposed in your cluster.

Considering the YAML you claim you used to get the ingress controller running, there is no sign of exposition to the outside network.

You need at least to define a `Service` to expose your controller (might be a load balancer if the provider where you put your cluster supports it), you can use `HostNetwork: true` or a `NodePort`.

To use the latest option (`NodePort`) you could apply this YAML:

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml

I suggest you read the Ingress documentation page to get a clearer idea about how all this stuff works.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Answer (score 0):

In order to **access you local Kubernetes Cluster PODs** a `NodePort` needs to be created. The `NodePort` will publish your service in every node using using its public IP and a port. Then you can access the service using any of the cluster IPs and the assigned port.

**Defining a NodePort in Kubernetes**:

[image: Kubernetes NodePort and proxy]

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service-np
  labels:
    name: nginx-service-np
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8082        # Cluster IP, i.e. http://10.103.75.9:8082
      targetPort: 8080  # Application port
      nodePort: 30000   # (EXTERNAL-IP VirtualBox IPs) i.e. http://192.168.50.11:30000/ http://192.168.50.12:30000/ http://192.168.50.13:30000/
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

See a full example with source code at [Building a Kubernetes Cluster with Vagrant and Ansible (without Minikube)](https://www.itwonderlab.com/ansible-kubernetes-vagrant-tutorial/).

The nginx ingress controller can be replaced also with **Istio** if you want to benefit from a service mesh architecture for:

- Load Balance traffic, external o internal
- Control failures, retries, routing
- Apply limits and monitor network traffic between services
- Secure communication

See [Installing Istio in Kubernetes under VirtualBox (without Minikube)](https://www.itwonderlab.com/installing-istio-in-kubernetes-under-virtualbox/).